# spring-boot: building only part of the context for tests

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-test

by default spring-boot does a lot of auto-discovery and registration of components based on classpath. same goes for tests. but let's say i want test my DAOs that uses spring-jpa. so there is no point in loading everything except Db layer (flyway, @Repository, datasource) as it takes much more time to run such tests.

how can i run tests that configure only this part of whole spring context?

Answer (score 2):

The `@DataJpaTest` annotation was created exactly for this use case: https://spring.io/blog/2016/04/15/testing-improvements-in-spring-boot-1-4#testing-the-jpa-slice